# How to apply index for this select query ($not, $exists) in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, performance, spring-boot, indexing

Suppose i have a collection "launch" where fields are department, userId , launch_status, booster

i want to get

```
{ department : "xxx" , userId: "john" , launch_status : { $not : { $eq : 
"LAUNCHED"} , booster : {$exists : true}}}
```

How do i apply index to this query?
A similar query is fired multiply times in my application, with NOT and EXISTS condition.
I have applied index on all these columns like

```
db.launch.createIndex({department : 1, userId : 1, launch_status :1 , 
booster :1})
```

Indexing is not working

Mongo DB is hitting its threshold because indexing is not getting applied
Please help

Comment: Could you add an [`explain`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to your question?

Comment: you mean explain() function of mongodb?

Comment: Yup! If `launch_status` always exists, one thing you could specify is `launch_status: {$exists: true}`. That way, the query planner will know that it can safely use the index (beause mongo doesn't index non-existence of a field, it won't be able to fully use the index, and if you check the query planner, I expect to see that it's looking up lots of documents)